# Send pictures in an email that are contained in a form stored in a Form Library

Tags: infopath, forms-library

I have created a form library where users can report things and add pictures to the form. When users click Save I need InfoPath to send out an email with some details taken from the form. I then have a second view that is the layout needed for the email, but when I send the email the picture fields do not send in the email.

Is there a way, without sending the actual form, to include the pictures in the email?

Thanks
Darrell